# Rails POST to API Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4, titanium, strong-parameters

Developing a Titanium Alloy JS android app and have a rails 4.1 app that is serving an API for authentication.  Here is the code

```
  def valid_login?
    ApiAuthenticator.new(user,filtered_params[:password]).valid?
  end

  def user
    @user ||= User.find_by(email: filtered_params[:email])
  end

  def filtered_params
    params.permit(:email, :password)
  end
```

I have tried this multiple ways but still get this error.

```
Started POST "/api/login" for 192.168.1.64 at 2015-02-27 16:52:52 -0600
Processing by Api::V1::LoginController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"rt@c.com"}
Unpermitted parameter: format
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["email", "rt@c.com"]]
Unpermitted parameter: format
Completed 400 Bad Request in 5ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

When i do a puts on the filtered_params i get this

```
{"email"=>"rt@c.com", "password"=>"password"}
```

I have tried this multiple ways including

1. Using scaler everywhere (i.e. params.permit(:email))
2. Accessing the has with symbols or string (this is hash with indifferent access that is returned by params.permit call

SOLUTION

I am using Titanium Studio (titanium alloy) to develop this and i was rendering the incorrect error code of 400.  I should have rendered a 401.  I was able to parse the message and display the proper error to the user on login.  That code looks like this in titanium alloy controller

```
function login() {
    var xhr=Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();    
    xhr.open('POST', url_login);

    xhr.onload = function(){
     if(this.status == '200'){
            tokenResponse = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            setToken(tokenResponse.token);          
            Alloy.Globals.logged_in = true;
            redirectToIssues();
     }        
    };

    xhr.onerror = function(e){
        tokenResponse = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        alert(tokenResponse.message);
        };

    var params = {
        'email' : $.email.value,
        'password' : $.password.value
    };
     xhr.send(params);
}
```

Comment: try params.permit(:email, :password, :format) in your filtered_params function

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, same error.  Format is json if that helps.

Comment: Also just wrapped the response in a respond to block for json.  Still same 400 Bad Request Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need to use `permit` at all here

```
  def valid_login?
    ApiAuthenticator.new(user,params[:password]).valid?
  end

  def user
    @user ||= User.find_by(email: params[:email])
  end
```

`permit` is only useful when you are doing mass assignment, ie things like `User.create(params[:user])`

Comment: Ok, i feel a little silly on this one.  This was an error on the client.  I was just rendering a 400 instead of the json message that i was sending back.  So I thought i was getting a random 400 but it was the correct 400, i just wasn't displaying the message.  Thanks for your help.